# Can't run kotlin project on Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to run android project on Android Studio 3.0

But the error occurs:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libRSSupport.so'
```

**Update**

here is link to project
https://github.com/Kolyall/kotlinproject

Comment: There must be a problem with one of your libraries, post your build gradle

Comment: And try to rebuild the project

Comment: @MartinDeSimone I have 5 modules, so if I add all gradle files the question will be large, so I added link to project

Answer (score 0):

Both modules `library_utils` and `library_utils_picasso` activate RenderScript (RS). That might be why `libRSSupport.so` is present multiple times. Maybe try to remove RS support from one of the module.

I don't have AS 3.0 installed but I'd look in that direction...